# How can I get a list of files in a directory

Tags: c#, file-io

I am having difficulty in counting the number of text files in a folder. I used these commands to get path. Now I want to count the number of text files in a folder.

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

string files = fbd.SelectedPath;
textBox2.Text = files;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to get the count of txt files then use this:

```
int count = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.txt").Length;
```

There's also a third parameter that you can use called *searchOption* which uses the `SearchOption` enumeration.

You can specify either `AllDirectories` or `TopDirectoryOnly`.

Comment: By my understanding `GetFiles` returns an array, so instead of `Count()` use `Length`.

Comment: Yes, but either-or will work. `Count()` is a LINQ extension method that is valid when working with arrays since they implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yes, but an IEnumerable has no property that keeps track of the number of items, so in theory it casts to an IEnumerable and reiterates every item to count manually, while an array already keeps track of it. In other words: It is faster to use `Length` directly, because at least it prevents type checking and casting.

Comment: Yes, `Count()` will almost certainly be more expensive than `Length`. For the sake of providing the optimal solution, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

just use Directory class

```
  string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath,"*.txt");
  textBox2.Text = fileEntries.Length.ToString() ;
```